# php sessions not being detected

Tags: php

I have a login page that I register two sessions username and password.  then redirect to another page.  Once at this page

```
$_SESSION['username'] = "";
$_SESSION['password'] = "";
```

after login check I have the next page check if the session is registered

```
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION["username"]){


continue

}else go back to login page
```

Once I'm logged in I want to go to another page that depending on if the session variable is set I display something different on the page.

So on the galery page I do

at the very top of page I do

```
<?php 
session_start();

?>
```

then further down where I want the button to be I do

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){


show a new button

}

?>
```

I get the button to show but at the top of the page I have

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent
```

and it messes up how my page is displayed.  Any ideas?  I have the session_start(); at the very begging of page I don't know why this is happening.  Any ideas?

[image: where my session_start() is located]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Headers already sent by PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php) (The reference question / answer)

Comment: The rest of the error message (that part you did not post) tells you in which line the output started. Use the information the error message gives you to solve your problem.

Comment: Did you do a session_start() before assigning those two session variables?

Comment: yes I did a session_start() before assigning those two variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll get that error if anything outputs to the browser before you call `session_start()`. For example, you can't do:

```
<?php

echo "Test";

session_start();
```

You also can't do:

```
 <?php session_start();
```

(note the space before the `<?php`)

Make sure **nothing** - no HTML, no blank lines, no spaces - is written out prior to your `session_start()` calls and you'll be fine.

Comment: theres nothing written. <?php is my very first line furthest left.

Comment: Is that file being included by something else? This is a very well known error, and in every single time I've ever seen it asked the eventual response is "oops, found where the whitespace was coming from".

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure there's **nothing** (whitespace, UTF-8 BOM) before your `<?php`. This also applies to any files you include before the `session_start()` call.

Answer (score 0):

Is the gallery page being included in another file?

```
<?php

// lots of php code

include('/path/to/gallery.php');

?>
```

If anything is being sent to the browser before the session_start(); it will create this error.

Comment: no the gallery.php is its own file. and there is nothing included in it.

Answer (score -1):

Session is a header, headers can't be sent after any output (even a single space). You got 2 options, place session_start() before ANY output or you could also use output buffering, this allows you to send headers after output.

Place this at the top of your script

```
ob_start();
```

And this at the end

```
echo ob_get_clean();
```